# Separation of Variables for Heat equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Consider the equation $u_t=\frac{1}{4}u_{xx}$ on $(0,1)$ such that $u_x(t,0)=0, u(t,1)=0.$

(a) Use separation of variables to write down the general solution to this equation.

(b) Write down a solution if $u(0,x) =7\cos(5πx/2)$.

Comment: What work have you done so far?

Comment: Not sure if this is correct but this is my solution to (a) $$u(t,x)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} F_ne^{-\frac{c^2n^2\pi^2}{L^2}t}\sin(\frac{n\pi x}{L})$$

$$\Rightarrow \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} F_ne^{-\frac{1}{4}n^2\pi^2t}\sin(n\pi x)$$

$$F_n=2\int_{0}^{1} f(x)\sin(n\pi x)dx$$

Not sure what to do from here.

Comment: This is my work for (b), still not quite sure if I am correct (b) $$7\cos(\frac{5\pi x}{2})=u(0,x)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}F_n\sin(n\pi x)e^0$$

$$\rightarrow F_n=\begin{cases}
 7 \hspace{.25cm} n=5\\
 0 \hspace{.25cm} n\neq5
 \end{cases}$$
 
 $$u(t,x)=7\cos(\frac{5\pi x}{2})e^{\frac{-25}{4}\pi^2t}$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, in order to solve the original equation, we want to assume that a solution of $u(x,t) = X(x)T(t)$ solves the problem. We then arrive to the relationship

$$ \dfrac{T'}{\frac{1}{4}T} = \frac{X''}{X} = -\lambda^2 $$

(It's always by convenience that we throw the $\frac{1}{4}$ with the equation in $T$)

Thus, we arrive to the two equations

$\begin{cases}
T'(t) + \frac{1}{4}\lambda^2 T = 0 \\
X''(x) + \lambda^2X=0,X'(0)=0, X(1)=0
\end{cases}
$

Leading to the solutions $T(t) = a e^{-\frac{\lambda^2 t}{4}}$, and
$X(x) = b \cos{\left( \lambda x \right)}$.

In order to satisfy $X(1)=0$, we must have $b\cos(\lambda)=0 \rightarrow \lambda = \frac{\pi}{2}(2n-1), n = 1, 2, 3...$

Thus we must have, by superposition, that

$$u(x, t) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n e^{-\frac{\pi^2}{16}(2n-1)^2 t} \cos{\left( \frac{\pi}{2}(2n-1) x \right)} $$

Whew. Now, lets suppose that $u(x, 0)= f(x)$. Then according to our solution,

$$f(t) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} A_n \cos{\left( \frac{\pi}{2}(2n-1) x \right)} $$.

Multiplying both sides by $\cos{\left( \frac{\pi}{2}(2m-1) x \right)}$, and integrating from 0 to 1. Using the fact that the cosines form an orthonormal basis, we have that

$$\int_0^1 f(t) \cos{\left( \frac{\pi}{2}(2n-1) x \right)} \, dx = A_n \int_0^1 \cos^2{\left( \frac{\pi}{2}(2n-1) x \right)}\, dx = \frac{1}{2}A_n$$

Thus

$$A_n = 2 \int_0^1 f(t) \cos{\left( \frac{\pi}{2}(2n-1) x \right)} \, dx $$

For the next problem, you completely have the right idea, but you're using it with the wrong series. You would have a lot more to do if you had a sine in the series if your initial solution was made up of cosines.