# Finding series solution for a PDE

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Find a series solution for the partial differential equation  $$u_{xx}+u_{yy}+u_y-u=0$$ for $x,y\in(0,1)$, subject to the boundary conditions $u(0,y)=u(1,y)=u(x,0)=0$ as well as $u(x,1)=x^2-x^3$

Here's my work so far and would appreciate if someone can confirm.

Separation of variables tells us that $u(x,y)=X(x)Y(y)$ and that $$X''(x)Y(y)+X(x)Y''(y)+X(x)Y'(y)-X(x)Y(y)=0$$. Factoring out terms we have $$X''(x)Y(y)+X(x)\big(Y''(y)+Y'(y)-Y(y)\big)=0$$ This becomes $$X''(x)Y(y)=-X(x)\big(Y''(y)+Y'(y)-Y(y)\big)$$ and further manipulation yields us $$\frac{X''(x)}{X(x)}=-\frac{Y''(y)+Y'(y)-Y(y)}{Y(y)}=\lambda$$

Now we have $$X''(x)-\lambda X(x)=0$$ and $$Y''(y)+Y'(y)+Y(y)(\lambda-1)=0$$

Looking back to our boundary conditions $$u(0,y)=u(1,y)=u(x,0)=0$$ which means that $$X(0)Y(y)=X(1)Y(y)=X(x)Y(0)=0$$

When $\lambda>0$ we have  $$X(x)=Ae^{\sqrt{\lambda}x}+Be^{-\sqrt{\lambda}x},$$ plugging in $0$ we have $X(0)=A+B=0$ therefore $A=-B$. Plugging in $1$ we have $$X(1)=Ae^{\sqrt{\lambda}}+Be^{-\sqrt{\lambda}}=0.$$ Plugging in $-B$ into $A$ we get $$Ae^{\sqrt{\lambda}}-Ae^{-\sqrt{\lambda}}=0.$$ Factoring out $A$ we have $$A(e^{\sqrt{\lambda}}-e^{-\sqrt{\lambda}})=0$$ and $$e^{\sqrt{\lambda}}-e^{-\sqrt{\lambda}}\neq0$$ therefore $A=0$ and $A=-B$ so $B=0$. Therefore $\lambda\ngtr 0$, else trivial solution.\

When $\lambda<0$ we have $X(x)=C\sin(\sqrt{\lambda}x)+D\cos(\sqrt{\lambda}x)$ From our boundary conditions we find that $X(0)=D=0$ and $X(1)=C\sin(\sqrt{\lambda})=0$ We assume $C\neq 0$ to avoid a trivial solution and as a result $\lambda=-\pi^2n^2$. Plugging this into our original equation we have $X(x)=C_n\sin(n\pi x)$.\

Going back to our equation for $Y(y)$ we have $$Y''(y)+Y'(y)+Y(y)(-n^2\pi^2-1)=0$$ and this gives us a characteristic polynomial of $$r^2+r+(-n^2\pi^2-1)=0$$ so $$r=\frac{-1\pm\sqrt{1-4(-n^2\pi^2 -1)}}{2}$$ which becomes $$r=\frac{-1+\sqrt{5+4n^2\pi^2}}{2},r=\frac{-1-\sqrt{5+4n^2\pi^2}}{2}$$ As a result $$Y(y)=E_ne^{y\frac{-1+\sqrt{5+4n^2\pi^2}}{2}}+F_ne^{y\frac{-1-\sqrt{5+4n^2\pi^2}}{2}}$$ Plugging in our boundary conditions we have $$Y(0)=E_n+F_n=0$$ therefore $E_n=-F_n$. Plugging this back into our equation we get $$Y(y)=E_ne^{y\frac{-1+\sqrt{5+4n^2\pi^2}}{2}}-E_ne^{y\frac{-1-\sqrt{5+4n^2\pi^2}}{2}}$$ Factoring terms out we have $$Y(y)=E_ne^{-\frac{y}{2}}\bigg(e^{y\frac{\sqrt{5+4n^2\pi^2}}{2}}-e^{-y\frac{\sqrt{5+4n^2\pi^2}}{2}}\bigg)$$ which further can be rewritten as $$Y(y)=2E_ne^{-\frac{y}{2}}\sinh\bigg(y\frac{\sqrt{5+4n^2\pi^2}}{2}\bigg)$$ Recall that $X(x)=C_n\sin(n\pi x)$ so our solution is of the for $$2C_nE_n\sin(n\pi x)e^{-\frac{y}{2}}\sinh\bigg(y\frac{\sqrt{5+4n^2\pi^2}}{2}\bigg)$$ We'll call $G_n=2C_nE_n$ to get $$u(x,y)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}G_n\sin(n\pi x)e^{-\frac{y}{2}}\sinh\bigg(\frac{y\sqrt{5+4n^2\pi^2}}{2}\bigg)$$ and $$u(x,1)=x^2-x^3=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}G_n\sin(n\pi x)e^{-\frac{1}{2}}\sinh\bigg(\frac{y\sqrt{5+4n^2\pi^2}}{2}\bigg)$$ For our grand finale we now find that $$G_n=\frac{\int_{0}^{1}(x^2-x^3)e^{-\frac{1}{2}}\sin(n\pi x)\sinh\bigg(y\frac{\sqrt{5+4n^2\pi^2}}{2}\bigg)dx}{\int_{0}^{1}e^{-\frac{1}{2}}\sin(n\pi x)\sinh\bigg(\frac{y\sqrt{5+4n^2\pi^2}}{2}\bigg)dx}$$ At this point I would use some super computer to evaluate this integral and substitute $G_n$ into $$G_n\sin(n\pi x)e^{-\frac{y}{2}}\sinh\bigg(\frac{y\sqrt{5+4n^2\pi^2}}{2}\bigg).$$

Comment: $X(0)=C=0$ is incorrect!

Comment: If $\lambda=-n^2\pi^2$ how $\sin\sqrt{\lambda}=0$.?

Comment: $\sinh\bigg(\frac{\sqrt{5+4n^2\pi^2}}{2}\color{red}{y}\bigg)$

Comment: Fixed the last part, for the other thing I'm still trying to work it out, my peer in the class said it was. Let me look over work some more

Comment: Honestly I am very lost trying to untangle the mess. Doesn't $\lambda$ need to be less than 0 in order for us to get $X(t)$ into that gen solution form?

Comment: When you suppose $\lambda>0$, let $\lambda=k^2$ and for $\lambda<0$ let $\lambda=-k^2$ these make solution simpler.

Comment: The rest is OK. except for $u(x,1)=x^2-x^3$ as far as I know there is not necessary to use  super computer, I remember that I used Fourier series for $x^2-x^3$.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I think I'll let the problem sit for now. If you have time these problems are really giving me difficulties as well. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2457738/solution-to-the-wave-equation 

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2456612/separation-of-variables-for-heat-equation

Thanks

Comment: Good luck!.....