# Solution to the wave equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Find a solution to the wave equation with $c=1$ on the unit interval with $u(t,0)=u(t,1)=0,u(0, x)= \sin(3πx)$, and $u_t(0,x)=4\sin(2πx)$.

I have some work for this, but no clue if I am on the right track.

I'm going to rewrite it as a summation and simplify it further

$$u(t,x)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} F_ne^{-\frac{c^2n^2\pi^2}{L^2}t}\sin(\frac{n\pi x}{L})$$

$$\Rightarrow \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} F_ne^{-\frac{1}{4}n^2\pi^2t}\sin(n\pi x)$$

$$=2\int_{0}^{1} f(x)\sin(n\pi x)dx$$

Now I evaluate it with respect to the boundaries

$$7\cos(\frac{5\pi x}{2})=u(0,x)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}F_n\sin(n\pi x)e^0$$

$$\rightarrow F_n=\begin{cases}
 7 \hspace{.25cm} n=5\\
 0 \hspace{.25cm} n\neq5
 \end{cases}$$

$$u(t,x)=7\cos(\frac{5\pi x}{2})e^{\frac{-25}{4}\pi^2t}$$

Comment: What are the values of $u(t,0)$ and $u(t,1)$ in the derived results. Are they equal to $0$???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Fourier series representation for $u(t,x)$ can be written

$$u(t,x)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n(t)\sin(n\pi x)$$

where $a_n(t)=A_ne^{n\pi t}+B_n e^{-n\pi t}$.

Applying the initial conditions reveals

$$A_n=\frac1\pi \delta_{n,2}+\frac12 \delta_{n,3}$$

and

$$B_n= -\frac1\pi \delta{n,2}+\frac12 \delta_{n,3}$$

where $\delta{n,k}$.is the Kronecker Delta.

Can you wrap it up now?

Comment: This makes things a lot clearer. I already turned in my problem set, but this makes me confident that I can do this in the future. Quick question, our class never went over the Kronecker Delta, what exactly is that?

Comment: Pleased to hear that this helped.  The Kronecker Delta is defined as $$\delta_{n,k}=\begin{cases}1&,n=k\\\\0&,n\ne k\end{cases}$$

Comment: Oh I see now. Yes this looks familiar, never knew this was the name for it.